# Trigger a pipeline when specific file is changed

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am creating a new CI pipeline that will be triggered anytime a .bicep file is changed and then zip up all of the files.

```
# Pipeline is triggered anytime there is a change to .bicep files
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - "feature/*"
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'
```

This pipeline works and is triggered anytime a change is made in the feature branch.

To target any .bicep files I am trying:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - "feature/*"
  paths:
    include:
      - '**/*.bicep'
```

I also tried to specify the entire route that holds the files:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - "feature/*"
  paths:
    include:
      - "src/Deployment/IaC/Bicep/*"
```

When I make a change to a .bicep file in the feature branch, the pipeline is never triggered so I know my syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE : WILDCARDS WERE NOT SUPPORTED BY AZURE PIPELINES WHEN THIS QUESTION WAS FIRST POSTED, BUT MICROSOFT HAS NOW REINTRODUCED WILDCARD SUPPORT AGAIN FOR PIPELINES. READ BELOW FOR THE FULL CONTEXT.**

Wildcards are not supported anymore for azure pipelines.
Instead just set the relative path to your Bicep folder like so :

```
paths:
include:
  - src/Deployment/IaC/Bicep
```

see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?tabs=yaml&view=azure-devops#paths
[image]

**EDIT :**
Looks like wildcards are supported again!

see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?tabs=yaml&view=azure-devops#paths
[image]

Comment: Did they remove wild card support and added it back again? The docs says it's supported now.

Comment: Seems like it was added back: _"Wilds cards are supported for path filters."_ - [docs link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?tabs=yaml&view=azure-devops#paths)